# ID3D11UnorderedAccessView data to StructuredBuffer

Tags: c++, directx, shader, effects, compute-shader

I have 2 effects. I've just started to work with shaders and DirectX, so sorry for stupid question.
Firts one with compute shader in it takes RWStructuredBuffer.

```
RWStructuredBuffer<Particle> Particles : register(u0);
```

Second one:

```
StructuredBuffer<Particle> Particles : register(t0);
```

I created data this way:

```
//creating buffer for initial particles
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbDesc = {};
cbDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Particle)*PARTICLES_COUNT;
cbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE::D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
//cbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS & D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
cbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
cbDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
cbDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
cbDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Particle);

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbuavDesc = {};
cbuavDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Particle)*PARTICLES_COUNT;
cbuavDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE::D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
//cbuavDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS & D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
cbuavDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_FLAG::D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
cbuavDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
cbuavDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
cbuavDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Particle);

// Fill in the subresource data.
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData = {};
InitData.pSysMem = &initialParticles;
InitData.SysMemPitch = sizeof(Particle)*PARTICLES_COUNT;
InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&cbDesc, &InitData, &solverParticles);
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&cbuavDesc, &InitData, &solverUAVParticles);

D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uvDesc = {};
uvDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
uvDesc.Buffer.NumElements = PARTICLES_COUNT;
uvDesc.Buffer.Flags = D3D11_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_COUNTER;
uvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
uvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC svDesc = {};
svDesc.Buffer.NumElements = PARTICLES_COUNT;
svDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
svDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
svDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;


hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(solverUAVParticles, &uvDesc, &g_uav);
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(solverParticles, &svDesc, &g_particlesStructuredBufferView);
```

And passed:

```
hr = g_particlesUAV->SetUnorderedAccessView(g_uav);
hr = g_particlesStructuredBuffer->SetResource(g_particlesStructuredBufferView);
```

Unfortunately second effect renders initial data, but I need to render already changed data from compute shader. I've not found any helpful samples. 
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details on how you use the buffers, it is hard to give a real solution. But what is weird is that you have two buffers, one is only uav, while the other only srv ! What you should have instead is one buffer for inplace update, or two doing a ping pong,  that are uav AND srv, so you can first update with the uav then use as a srv to render the particles.